# Django filter with annotate

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```
class Review(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(ReviewImage, blank=True, null=True)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    review = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=1)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    changed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

# This is the problem... I works, but no vendor is shown if there is no review.
vendor_list = (Vendor.objects.filter(category=category,
                                     review__product__isnull=True,
                                     active=True)
               .annotate(rating_avg=Avg('review__rating')))
```

HOW can I do it with `review__product__isnull=True`? If there is no review at all, I still want the vendor, but the rating should be: "0", .. what to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553038/treat-null-as-0-in-django-model

Comment: Can you detail what you are trying to do ? it seems like you are trying to get vendors without review but the use of Avg is confusing.

Comment: I want to list all vendors i the category, and show the rating for each ... but I only want the rating where a "product" is not selected .. Thank for helping!

Comment: @Secator: that's a very useful answer (both for the use of `COALESCE` and for the monkey-patching of Django's aggregates), but it's hard to apply in this case because of the need for an `OUTER JOIN` on the review's product field. (If you know a good way to express this in Django's query language, I'd love to see it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if I understand this. You are trying to list all active vendors in the category, annotated with the average rating of their reviews. The way you determine that a review is a vendor review rather than a product review is that the product field is null. And you want the average rating of vendors with no reviews to be zero.

In SQL your query requires an [`OUTER JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_joins):

```sql
SELECT vendor.id, COALESCE(AVG(review.rating), 0.0) AS rating
  FROM myapp_vendor AS vendor
  LEFT OUTER JOIN myapp_review AS review
    ON review.vendor_id = vendor.id
       AND review.product IS NULL
  WHERE vendor.category = %s
    AND vendor.active
  GROUP BY vendor.id
```

Sometimes in Django the simplest solution is a [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/sql/): as the developers say, the database API is "[a shortcut but not necessarily an end-all-be-all.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#option-to-drop-into-raw-sql-easily-when-needed)" So that would look like this:

```python
for v in Vendor.objects.raw('SELECT ... ', [category]): # query as above
    print 'Vendor {0} has rating {1}'.format(v.name, v.rating)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ... thanks ;) ... Don't know if my "product" / "vendor" review solution is the best one?, to keep it in one table? .

Answer (score 0):

OK I might be wrong here. I did a small test and it gave me the correct result but I would have to spend more time testing and I don't have that now.

You could try this:

```
vendor_list = Vendor.objects.filter(category=category, active=True)
vendor_list = vendor_list.filter(Q(review__product__isnull=True)|Q(review__isnull=True)).annotate(rating_avg=Avg('review__rating'))
```

(The filter has been separated in to 2 lines to make it easier to read but could be merged)

The idea is that you first take all vendors and then filter those who either has no product reviews or no reviews at all. Then you annotate those.

The rating for those vendors missing a review would be None not 0.