# Nested query with aggregated Foreign Key

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have **two models like so**:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    raising = models.DecimalField()

class Investment(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    amount  = models.DecimalField()
```

Now **I want to find all companies where cumulative investments are *less* than `raising`**

If I added a dynamic property to Company called `raised_so_far` that aggregated the investment amounts, I could do something like so:

```
Company.objects.filter(raised_so_far__lt=F('raising'))
```

but filtering happens at the SQL level so that's not possible.

So far, this is my best attempt:

```
Company.objects.filter(raising__gt=Investment.objects.filter(company=F(outer_company_object)).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum'] or 0)
```

How do I filter on an aggregation of a foreign key **using a parent object**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to annotate the queryset with the total investments (handled via a join), then query using an `F` object to use the annotated value like a field.

```
Company.objects.annotate(total_investments=models.Sum('investments__amount')).filter(raising__gt=models.F('total_investments'))
```

And, you're off to the raises.

Comment: Thanks, totally simple and it works.. except for Companies raising money with no Investments (they're left out of the list). This is due to Sum returning None and not 0 though, [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553038/treat-null-as-0-in-django-model)

Comment: What if there was a 3rd level to the hierarchy above `Company`, call it `ParentCompany`. Is there an `annotate` expression that would allow you to sum all investments across all companies in the parent?

Comment: @AddisonKlinke you can make a `GROUP BY` query like this:

`Investment.objects.values('company__parent__name').annotate(total=models.Sum('amount'))`. And, you can filter the results on that annotated field - for example: `Investment.objects.values('company__parent__name').annotate(total=models.Sum('amount')).filter(total__gt=models.F('company__raising'))`. Just beware that with a `GROUP BY` annotated queryset, if you try to do things like output values other than those annotated or listed in `values(...)` (parent name in this case), you'll get confusing results; and this is normal.