# Let Sum() Return 0 instead of nothing

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to perform a query with djangos orm which returns how many licenses a section used in a certain period of time.
I'm using django 1.8.3 and python 2.7.6 and mysql as database.

My query looks similar to this:

```
beg = datetime.date(2015, 9, 1)
end = datetime.date(2015, 9, 9)
LicenseUsage.objects.all().filter(datestamp__range=[beg, end])\
                          .values('datestamp')\
                          .filter(groupid__in=[301, 274, 155, 186])\
                          .filter(poolid=301)\
                          .annotate(used=Sum('usedamount'))\
                          .order_by('datestamp')
```

The result contains datestamp and usedamount

```
[{'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 1), 'used': 2},
 {'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 2), 'used': 1},
 {'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 3), 'used': 2},
 {'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 4), 'used': 2},
 {'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 5), 'used': 1}, 
 {'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 7), 'used': 2}, # <-- where is the 6.?
 {'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 8), 'used': 2},
 {'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 9), 'used': 1}])
```

My problem is that my query doesn't return anything if a section hasn't used a license on a certain day.
i.e. the 6. September 2015 in my result.

I would like to preform a query which returns

```
[{'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 1), 'used': 2},
 {'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 2), 'used': 1},
 {'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 3), 'used': 2},
 {'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 4), 'used': 2},
 {'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 5), 'used': 1},
 {'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 6), 'used': 0}, # <--- This is what i want
 {'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 7), 'used': 2},
 {'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 8), 'used': 2},
 {'datestamp': datetime.date(2015, 9, 9), 'used': 1}])
```

I tried Coalesce

```
LicenseUsage.objects.all().filter(datestamp__range=[beg, end])\
                          .values('datestamp')\
                          .filter(groupid__in=[301, 274, 155, 186])\
                          .filter(poolid=301)\
                          .annotate(used=Coalesce(Sum('usedamount'), V(0)))\
                          .order_by('datestamp')
```

but the result is the same and it seems i'm not getting it right.
Anybody knows if this kind of query is possible with djangos orm and if its possible how to solve it?
Would appreciate some help, because this is driving me nuts.

Thanks in advance.

BigZ

Comment: This would help you [treat-null-as-0-in-django-model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553038/treat-null-as-0-in-django-model)

Comment: Is there a row in the LicenseUsage table for the datetime you expect to get zero for?

Comment: No, the LicenseUsage table only gets new entries when a group or section uses a license. If they are not using any license there is no entry.
@luoluo thanks, i will take a look at it and see if it solves my problem