# Django what to use instead of null?

Tags: python, django

I am doing return of investment calculation (ROI) and the formula is

```
((Net returns - Actual investment) / Actual investment ) * 100

For Ex: (( 2000 - 1000 ) / 1000 ) * 100 = 100%
```

So in this, there is an problem: Initially the returns would be 0 until returns actually comes in ! By that, the above calculation shows -100%

so i thought of using Null initally, so that if its null we can show 0% and when the value changes from null to something we can show respective ROI.

The problem is, i cant perform addition on Null value,

```
_investment = F('returns') + 2000
    _investment .save()
```

As the returns field is set to null F expression couldn't perform addition operation, so how to handle this ? As i cant set the default value as "0" and use if condition base on it - because there may be some negative returns also.

Please suggest some way to tackle this !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Treat NULL as '0' in Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553038/treat-null-as-0-in-django-model)

Comment: Use `Coalesce` as described in above linked duplicate target and pass the second argument as `F('actual_investment')`, that should get you 0 as the result. (Note: see the second answer, it is better than the accepted one)

Comment: Does ```Net Returns``` include ```Actual Investment``` and ```Returns on Investment``` ? Your formula is ambiguous.

Comment: It includes actual investment also @Ram

Comment: If it includes actual investment, then how  ```Net Returns``` will be 0 initially ? Initially ```Net Returns``` will be equal to ```Actual Investment``` and so the difference is 0 and your formula gives 0% and not -100%. Is it ?

Comment: Why would be Net Returns be equal to Actual Investment initially ? For that purpose only we are subtracting net returns with Actual Investment. @Ram

Comment: From your **previous comment**, ```Net Returns = Actual Investment + Returns```. So initially there are no returns i.e, ```Returns = 0``` and that means ```Net Returns = Actual Investment```.

Comment: Ya logically correct, but am just directly using 0 to manage the initial things ! what difference it gonna make ?

Answer (score 0):

How about use @property that will compute the logic you need?

```
class YourModel():

    @property
    def count_roi(self):
        if self.returns - self.actual_investment < 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return ((self.returns - self.actual_investment ) / self.actual_investment ) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the value of "actual investment" as the initial value of the "net returns" although I believe "net returns" is a misnomer here and it should actually be "current value" (of the investment). Returns are generally what's left after deducting your initial investment i.e. current value - actual investment.

`Returns = current value - actual investment`

`ROI = (returns / actual investment) * 100`